# Points shapefile from QGIS to Android?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, android, navigation

**I have** a points shapefile in QGIS with 40 groups of 20 points each (total of 800 points). For each point I have stored many information.

**I need** to check this information and add more moving on the map by car.

**How can I share** the QGIS coordinates of each point to an Android smartphone to get each point?

It would be great to share it with an online service (e.g. importing in Google Maps account or something similar)

ORIGINAL QUESTION WAS: I need to share a 800-point QGIS shapefile with android smartphone for offline navigation.

Considering the high number of points I would need to set up some filter so that navigation is as easy as possible.

I use QGIS 2.18 and different standard android smartphone

Answer (score 3):

It's not a direct answer to your question (which is a bit unclear to me)  but you might be interested to have a go at **[Qfield](http://www.opengis.ch/android-gis/qfield/)** which is a mix between QGIS and an Android app.

Basically, you need to create a QGIS project you just need to store on your android phone. You will be able to look at the features and edit attributes if needed.

> QField (for much more information refer to QField.org) allows you to
>   take your QGIS projects out of the office for effective field work. By
>   maintaining QGIS’ styling and edit widgets QField greatly reduces
>   preparation time.
>
> QField is an Open Source project led by OPENGIS.ch LLC and the source
>   code is on github. A possibility to donate to the project can be found
>   on the donate page (preferred) or by buying the QField for QGIS Karma
>   edition app.
>
> Also if you need a specific feature, contact us to sponsor its
>   development.
>
> QField is built from ground up to be touch oriented and easy to use
>   outside. and follows the following paradigm:
>
> - GPS centric
> - QGIS desktop compatible
> - Fully working when offline
> - Synchronization capabilities
> - Project preparation on desktop
> - Few and large buttons
> - Switchable use paradigm (Display, Digitizing, Measuring, Inspection,…)
>
> QField is built using Qt5, QtQuick 2 (both are supported
>   and suggested by Qt) and OpenGL so it is future proof and it
>   spearheads QGIS towards Qt5.
>
> Since version 0.4.1,  QField does support Android 5+ (min suggested
>   4.3, min required 4.0.3).

Answer (score 2):

You can try [NextGIS Mobile](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-mobile/)

[image]

NextGIS Mobile accepts GeoJSON (can be easily obtained from QGIS). ESRI Shape file support will be in v3. Also you can get QGIS map with symbology using [QTiles plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qtiles/). And finally using [nextgis.com](http://nextgis.com/) cloud web GIS you can synchronize your spatial data with all platforms - Web browser, QGIS and other mobile devices.
Nice form can be prepared in [Formbuilder](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-formbuilder) and load to NextGIS Mobile.

[image]

Take a look at documentation: http://docs.nextgis.com/ngmobile_dev/toc.html

The FOSS4G 2016 talk: [presentation](http://nextgis.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/NextGIS-mobile-FOSS4G-2016.pdf) and [video](http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/misc/openstreetmap/FOSS4G-2016/foss4g-2016-1233-nextgis_mobile_-_mobile_gis_alternative-hd.webm)

Another [small video](https://youtu.be/STLhTvxmYPE).

Answer (score 1):

One option would be:

1. Open QGIS Desktop and add in shapefile
2. Download/enable qgis2web plugin
3. Open up plugin and create either OpenLayers 3 or Leaflet map/app
4. Finally, convert your web map javascript app created in step 3 to an Android app, like [Converting Your JavaScript App to an Android App w/ PhoneGap](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-10-22-how-to-convert-your-javascript-app-into-an-android-app-with-phonegap/)

Another option would be:

1. Install QGIS Android app on your device, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qgis.qgis
2. Open up QGIS and add in your shapefile on your device

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you are dealing with mobile never use geojson. Because all of FILE gets loaded into memory. Use tippecanoe by mapbox to generate vector tiles mbtiles with gzipped pbf in tiles table tile_data blob